# How to recreate the same "base and instance of" relationship that `object` and `type` hold in Python?

Tags: python, metaclass

I'm learning knowledge about metaclass recently. I learnt that `isinstance(object, type)` and `issubclass(type, object)`. I want to write self-defined class act like `object` and `type`, but how to declare class when circular dependency is happened? the pseudo code is as follow:

```
declare class MyType

class MyObject(metaclass=MyType):
    pass

class MyType(MyObject, type):
    pass
```

Comment: You can't, not in Python. You might be able to with a C extension, but Python uses *bootstrapping* to set up that dependency, which involves mutating internal data that isn't, under normal circumstances, meant to be mutated.

Comment: I don't know why this was closed. Neither of the suggested questions are duplicates of this. Just because they all deal with metaclasses does not mean this is not a valid question unto itself, albeit being poorly worded.

Comment: Sure - this is not a duplicate. Reopening.
Someone _might_ come up with some workaround to do what the OP is asking for. Not that I can imagine it being of any practical use - but then, I guess a lot of metaclass questions are for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the very appropriate comment above:

"""
You can't, not in Python. You might be able to with a C extension, but Python uses bootstrapping to set up that dependency, which involves mutating internal data that isn't, under normal circumstances, meant to be mutated. –
Silvio Mayolo
""".

Well, that, while correct, is not entirely true - Python dynamicism allows one to change, in a limited form, classes bases and inheritance, and even object classes, *after* a class or object is created.

That means that part of the same bootstrapping can be performed in pure Python code.

There is a *second* hard-coded relationship in Python that you don't mention in your question: `type` is own metaclass - that is `type` is an instance of `type`: that really can't be emulated in pure Python code. The mutual relationship of `type` and `object` however, can. Again, that is of no practical use whatsoever, and `object` and `type` are always kept in the loop as baseclass and base metaclass: you can't really do anything without them.

That said, check the examples bellow.

First thing is that `type` is quite unique, not due to this relationship with `object`, but because it does all the job for actually creating a class in Python under the hood - and that is a lot of things. Eventually all custom metaclasses have at some point to call `type.__new__` to actually create a type - so while your `MyType` can be made to inherit from `MyObject`, it will also have to retain inheritance from `type` (as one of the bases) - so that class creation job can be done. (ok - eventually, there is a way out of it, with overriding the right methods, and proxying calls to `type` - but lets deffer that).

Fact is: to gain this egg-hen relation ship you have to change at least one of your objects *after* it is created.

It is not possible to modify a class` class (its metaclass) after it is created:

```
class A: pass

class M(A, type): pass

A.__class__ = M
```

Will raise `TypeError: __class__ assignment only supported for mutable types or ModuleType subclasses` . But the converse is actually possible:

```
class M(type): pass

class A(metaclass=M): pass

M.__bases__ = (A, type)
```

As I wrote above, one needs to keep `type` as one of the bases for M - trying to remove it from the bases in the assignment, will raise: `TypeError: __bases__ assignment: 'A' object layout differs from 'type'` . But doing `M.__bases__ = (A, type)` works, and after doing that:

```
In [18]: isinstance(A, M)
Out[18]: True

In [19]: issubclass(M, A)
Out[19]: True
```

Now, for the second part, if you don't want `M` to inherit from `type` at all, just implementing `__new__` and `__call__`  on `M` suffices for having a "working metaclass".
HOWEVER, there is no way then to pass `M` as the first parameter in the call to `type.__new__`: Python checks internally that the metaclass passed in this call is a "real" subclass of `type`. This means that when you ask for the class of  `A` subsequently, it won't say it is a "class of M"  using normal methods - but then, we can "falsify" that somewhat, by implementing the `__instancecheck__` special method in the "metaclass of the metaclass".

Note that due to some of the restrictions in `__bases__` assignmen, and to the fact that `__instancecheck__` must live on the metahclass of the class whose instance we want to check (so, in the metaclass of our metaclass), we need 2 other intermediate classes now.

The code in `__instancecheck__` and `__subclasscheck__` bellow can be tweaked to perform some "real checking" - just returning "True" is enough for demonstration purposes:

```
class A: pass


class M(type):
    def __instancecheck__(self, instance):
        return True
    def __subclasscheck__(self, subclass):
        return True
    
class N(A, metaclass=M):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, ns):
        cls = type.__new__(type, name, bases, ns) # <- here, M can't be the first argument, as it does not inherit from "type"
        return cls
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
        if isinstance(instance, cls):
            instance.__init__(*args, **kw)
        return instance
        
class B(metaclass=N): pass

N.__bases__ = (N,)
```

And now, with a metaclass not inheriting from type, you can have:

```
In [42]: isinstance(B, N)
Out[42]: True

In [43]: issubclass(N, B)
Out[43]: True
```

However, if the test is made through `type` you won't see `N` as the metaclass:

```
In [44]: type(B)
Out[44]: type
```